# How to save string into a text file by using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a string, it shows as follow:

```
Str = '+1 3:0.045 7:1.726 8:0.63'
```

My question is how to save the string into a text file by using Matlab. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fileID = fopen ('fileName.txt', 'w') ;
Str = ‘+1 3:0.045 7:1.726 8:0.63’ ;
fprintf(fileID, str) ;
```

Comment: you did not specify the location of the saved file.How to specify the location?

Comment: @PeterLi It goes into the current working directory.

Comment: @David: Thanks for explanation. Due to weekend, I could not access my computer and saw this conversation very late.

Comment: @PeterLi: You can specify the complete path to text file in which you want to save data instead of 'fileName.txt'. It is my mistake that I could not provide the details.